Delphi's "XML Databinding interfaces" feature doesn't work as expected on "List-Items"
I have used Delphi's "XML Data-Binding Interfaces" to create an XML file from an XSD-file, but I have failed to make it produce an output that follows the requested structure.
This happens when I use lists. The code below will, I hope, visualize it:
...

implementation

var
  inv: IXMLInvoiceWood;
const
  XMLFile = '../../../TestInvoiceFile.xml';

{$R *.dfm}

procedure setReference(const pmcInv: IXMLInvoiceWood; const pmcAssignedBy, pmcRefName: string);
var
  Ref: IXMLInvoiceReference;
begin
  ref := pmcInv.InvoiceWoodHeader.InvoiceReference.Add;
  ref.SetAttributeNS('AssignedBy','',pmcAssignedBy);
  ref.SetAttributeNS('InvoiceReferenceType','',pmcRefName);
  ref.Attributes[pmcRefName] := 87532;
end;

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if inv = nil then
  inv := NewInvoiceWood;
  begin
    inv.OwnerDocument.Encoding := 'utf-8';
    inv.OwnerDocument.Options := inv.OwnerDocument.Options - [doAttrNull] + [doAutoSave] + [doNodeAutoIndent] + [doNodeAutoCreate];
    inv.InvoiceType := 'Invoice';
    inv.InvoiceWoodHeader.InvoiceNumber := '123456789';
    SetReference(Inv, 'seller', 'LoadingOrderNo');
    Inv.OwnerDocument.SaveToFile(XMLFile);

    mmo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);
  end;

This produces the following output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoiceWood InvoiceType="Invoice">
  <InvoiceWoodHeader>
    <InvoiceNumber>123456789</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceReference AssignedBy="seller" InvoiceReferenceType="LoadingOrderNo" LoadingOrderNo="87532"/>
  </InvoiceWoodHeader>
</InvoiceWood>

But it should look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoiceWood InvoiceType="Invoice">
  <InvoiceWoodHeader>
    <InvoiceNumber>123456789</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceReference AssignedBy="Seller" InvoiceReferenceType="LoadingOrderNo">87532</InvoiceReference>
  </InvoiceWoodHeader>
</InvoiceWood>

What have I done wrong?

Your issue has nothing to do with lists.
If you want the number to appear in the text of the InvoiceReference node and not in an attribute of the node, then simply don't assign it to an attribute to begin with.
Inside setReference(), this line is wrong:
ref.Attributes[pmcRefName] := 87532;

It should be this instead:
ref.NodeValue := 87532;

Or this:
ref.Text := IntToStr(87532);
//or:
//ref.Text := '87532';


Very good! That made it! Well I added some code to my question above that will explain why I talked about lists. The ref := pmcInv.InvoiceWoodHeader.InvoiceReference.Add indicates that I added an InvoiceReference to a list contained by InvoiceHeader. So your answer confused me a bit.

@larand The fact that you are working with lists is irrelevant to the problem. It affects only a single node, and is not dependent on whether that node is in a list or not. I have reverted your edit to your question, as that detail is not useful to understanding the problem.
